# Android Fragment TextView setText from activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm having a problem: I have TabLayout with two tabs. One Tab contains a TextView.
I want to change the text of the TextView from MainActivity (later from a Thread in MainActivity). But it throws an NPE and I don't know how to solve it.

Here is my MainActivity.java-code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

public static ThreadConnected myThreadConnected;
TabTerminal tabT;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    tabT = new TabTerminal();
    tabT.setText("324");
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabControl tab1 = new TabControl();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabTerminal tab2 = new TabTerminal();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

}

And here is the Fragment with TextView:

```
public class TabTerminal extends Fragment {

static TextView txtterminalout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_terminal, container, false);
    TextView txtterminalout = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.terminalout);

    return rootView;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    TextView t = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.terminalout);
    t.setText(text);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please add the exception details?

Comment: Looks like your getView() is returning null. Call this method in your onResume() of your MainActivity

Comment: and in Case 1: return tabT; instead of creating new TabTerminal()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your `setText()` method in your `fragment` from your `MainActivity` like this:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

//if you added fragment via layout xml
YourFragmentClass fragment =  (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
fragment.setText();
```

If you added fragment via code and used a `tag` string when you added your `fragment`, use `findFragmentByTag` instead like this:

```
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentByTag("yourTag");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of `onCreate()` you are creating new Fragment and trying to `setText()` to it. Since it is not inflated you are getting NPO.

What you want is to grab already inflated fragment and `setText()` on it.
Try `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment).setText()`